# Poisson Question Derivation

Tags: poisson-distribution

How is the second last line obtained from the line before it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$y$ varies from $x$ to $\infty$.

So, let $z= y-x \Rightarrow z$ varies from $0$ to $\infty$

$$\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^z}{z!} = e^{(1-p)\lambda}$$

This is the Sigma notation of $${e^x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comment: And this is the maclaurin expansion of the exponential function,
$$
e^{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$

Comment: @Mikal I was adding that one :)

Comment: Ah didn't mean to steal your thunder.